# Javascript Mapping Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects ("array"), each containing other arrays of objects.

```
[
  {
     name: "Object 1",
     question: [{value: "This", type: "text"}, {value: "is", type: "text"},  {value: "1", type: "number".]
     answer: [{value: "Answer", type: "text"}, {value: "is", type: "text"},  {value: "1", type: "number".]
  },
  {
     name: "Object 2",
     question: [{value: "This", type: "text"}, {value: "is", type: "text"},  {value: "2", type: "number".]
     answer: [{value: "Answer", type: "text"}, {value: "is", type: "text"},  {value: "2", type: "number".]
  },
]
```

In React, I'd like to render out the below:

```
<Typography>This</Typography><Typography>is</Typography><Number>1</Number>
<Typography>Answer</Typography><Typography>is</Typography><Number>1</Number
<Typography>This</Typography><Typography>is</Typography><Number>2</Number>
<Typography>Answer</Typography><Typography>is</Typography><Number>2</Number
```

I have tried the below, but can't work out why some of it won't map correctly.

```
array.map(snippet => {
 snippet.question.map(question => {
  return something here;
})
```

EDITED AS FORGOT A LEVEL OF OBJECTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this.

```
array.map(snippet => (
  <>
    {snippet.question.map(que => {
      if (que.type === "text") {
        return <Typography>{que.value}</Typography>;
      } else if (que.type === "number") {
        return <Number>{que.value}</Number>;
      }
      return null;
    })}
    {snippet.answer.map(ans => {
      if (ans.type === "text") {
        return <Typography>{ans.value}</Typography>;
      } else if (ans.type === "number") {
        return <Number>{ans.value}</Number>;
      }
      return null;
    })}
  </>
));
```

Comment: Apologies, I had a mistake in the question so have edited it. Apologies.